# How to use initializations.normal in Keras2.2.4

Tags: python, keras

I learn He's NCF code from [Github](https://github.com/hexiangnan/neural_collaborative_filtering/blob/master/MLP.py), He use Keras 1.0.7 and Theano 0.8.0.
These codes can't run in my Keras 2.2.4, like the "initializations". How to change them?

```
MLP_Embedding_User = Embedding(input_dim = num_users, output_dim = layers[0]/2, name = 'user_embedding',
                              init = init_normal, W_regularizer = l2(reg_layers[0]), input_length=1)

def init_normal(shape, name=None):
    return initializations.normal(shape, scale=0.01, name=name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keras2 API is not backwards compatible with Keras API and you are likely to have more problems like that coming up. If you have a chance, I suggest you install Keras 1.0.7 to run this example.

If you feed adventurous though, please take a look at the [Embedding layer definition](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/) in Keras2 docs:

```
keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim, output_dim, embeddings_initializer='uniform', embeddings_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, embeddings_constraint=None, mask_zero=False, input_length=None)
```

> embeddings_initializer: Initializer for the embeddings matrix (see
>   [initializers](https://keras.io/initializers/)).

So to answer your question, in Keras2 you do not need to explicitly create the initializer. It is sufficient to pass the initializer type as a string to the Embedding layer as such.

```
MLP_Embedding_User = Embedding(input_dim = num_users, output_dim = layers[0]/2, name ='user_embedding',
embeddings_initializer='uniform', W_regularizer = l2(reg_layers[0]), input_length=1)
```

(note that I only changed that one parameter. You will likely have to do other adjustments, i.e. replace `W_regularizer` to `embeddings_regularizer` to make it run)

Comment: well...maybe I must try Keras1. After change like yours, there also error:     
 Traceback (most recent call last):
......  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\learn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 60, in _SatisfiesTypeConstraint
    ", ".join(dtypes.as_dtype(x).name for x in allowed_list)))
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'shape' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64

Comment: migrating will indeed take some effort. But it will also offer a better opportunity to learn.